# Need to get decimal places value by providing format like "0.0000" in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I get a number with decimal places according to given format in jQuery?

```
var format = "0.0000";
var number = "123456.78910123";
```

The result should be `123456.7891`;

var format = "0.000";
    var number = "123456.78910123";

The result should be `123456.789`;

Comment: Try `123456.78910123.toFixed(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the length of digits (0s) after the decimal point and use that value in `toFixed()` function:

```js
function getFormatted(format, number){
  var length = format.split('.')[1].length;
  return parseFloat(number).toFixed(length);
}

var format = "0.0000";
var number = "123456.78910123";
console.log(getFormatted(format, number));
format = "0.00";
console.log(getFormatted(format, number));
```